# Discord.js (14.1) - Message Handler Not Responding

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

I have written a reasonably large Discord Bot in Python and now learning JS. I have read the documentation on this and checked intents etc. against my original Python Bot, but I simply cannot get the message handler to trigger the "message detected" alert on any channels in my server regardless of permissions etc. I've also set the permissions in the Developer Portal. Is there something stupid I'm missing here?!

````
import { Client, Message, GatewayIntentBits } from 'discord.js';

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    ],
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('ready!');
});

client.on('message', async (message) => {
    console.log("Message Detected");
    await message_handler(message);
});

async function message_handler(message: Message) {
    if (client.user && message.mentions.has(client.user.displayName, { ignoreEveryone: true })) {
        console.log("Mention Rule Triggered")
        await (message.channel.send)(`Hello ${message.author.displayName}, I'm the new Community Manager!`)
  }
}

client.login('******');```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

discord.js deprecated and in v14 removed the `message` event, it is now [`messageCreate`](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.14.1/Client:Class#messageCreate)!

> The `message` and interaction events are now removed. Use `messageCreate` and `interactionCreate` instead.

https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#events.

Comment: Thank you so much! I must have flicked to an older version on docs somehow, no idea how I still had message...

Comment: @R4pt0r there still is a message event even in the new Version under [Shard#message](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/main/Shard:Class#message), but that only is for messages between the shard instances